# MS Access form disappearing when switching to Form view

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that was working, then eventually when I go from Design view to Form view it just disappears, there are no errors and I cannot see it anywhere. The form is open, as I checked in the Immediate window with, Forms(0).Name

I tried:
repairing the database.
creating a new database and importing all the objects.
copying the form, removing all the controls and code - then opening the form, and it still disappears.

version: Microsoft Access 365/2021, Version 16. Subscription version

Comment: Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

1. Save the form as text using this command:

```
SaveAsText acForm, "YourFormName", "C:\Test\YourFormName.txt"
```

2. Rename the form in Access to, say, "YourFormName_old"
3. Open the file with a text editor like Notepad and locate the *Top* and *Left* entries
4. Set these to a low value, say 100:

```
Version =21
VersionRequired =20
PublishOption =1
Checksum =-1703185324
Begin Form
    PopUp = NotDefault
    DividingLines = NotDefault
    AllowDesignChanges = NotDefault
    DefaultView =0
    PictureAlignment =2
    DatasheetGridlinesBehavior =3
    GridY =10
    Width =2093
    DatasheetFontHeight =11
    ItemSuffix =2
    Left =100
    Top =100
    Right =15465
    Bottom =13815
    DatasheetGridlinesColor =14806254
```

5. Save the file
6. Load the form using this command:

```
LoadFromText acForm, "YourFormName", "C:\Test\YourFormName.txt"
```

7. Open the form. It will display at top-left